# Confconsole or something similar

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2

I want to have a display on my virtaul ubuntu machine, which shows me the IP adress an some other infos (for example: ports from the apache server)
The idea is from [Turnkey-Linux](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/) 's **Confconsole**

[image: pic]
Is there any software? (turnkey stopped to support Ubuntu in [2012](http://archive.turnkeylinux.org/ubuntu/pool/))

Answer (score 0):

I found the [configconsole on Github](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/confconsole). But it needs the [Python Libary from Turnkey](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/turnkey-pylib) too.

Then I get the console but without the Advenced Menu. It crashes as soon as I want to klick on something.

Comment: FWIW it should still run ok on Ubuntu, but as you note, it also needs the TurnKey pylib. So you could add the TurnKey apt repo and install from TurnKey. The only other thing that you'll need to ensure though, is that you install "python-dialog" from the TurnKey repo (rather than from the default Ubuntu one). I hope that helps...